# StaticInjectorError AppModule UsersListComponent -> UsersListService angular 5

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am practicing how to bind data to the Angular Material Datatables and I came across this error in my Console while binding my data.I searched number of forums but cant find answer to my problem so please spend some time and clear my error.Thanks in Advance.

**Model**

```ts
export interface User {
    name: string;
}
```

**Service**

```ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from '../_models/userModel';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class UsersListService {
    private url = 'http://localhost:3000/api/users';

constructor(public http: HttpClient) { }

    getUser():Observable<User[]> {
        return this.http.get<User[]>(this.url);
    }
}
```

**Component**

```ts
import { UsersListService } from './../_services/usersList.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { MatTableDataSource, MatSort, MatSortable } from "@angular/material";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-usersList',
  templateUrl: './usersList.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./usersList.component.css']
})
export class UsersListComponent implements OnInit {
  usersList = [];
  displayedColumns= ["name"];
  dataSource;

  constructor(private UsersListService:UsersListService) {
    /* this.usersData(); */
   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.UsersListService.getUser().subscribe( results => {
      if(!results) {
        return;
      }
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(results);
    });
  }
```

**HTML**

```html
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

**ERROR**

```
ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[UsersListComponent -> UsersListService]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[UsersListComponent -> UsersListService]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for UsersListService!
    at _NullInjector.get (core.js:1003)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1301)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1243)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1111)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1301)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1243)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1111)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:10896)
    at NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:12129)
    at resolveDep (core.js:12619)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add your service to you app.module in the section that it says providers

```
import { YourService } from "./the_location_of_your_service";
.
.
.

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    UserListComponent,
  ],
  imports: [BrowserModule],
  providers: [YourService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot....I just forgot to add that in my providers and was searching where I got the error

Comment: By the way how u know that I forgot to add it??? With ur experience or by using the error I posted???

Comment: Because when you generate a service from the CLI it doesn't add the service by default. It happens to everyone, I literally had that same problem 2 days ago because I forgot to add it lol

Comment: haha gud to remember the errors we faced...Thanks u solved my problem....